# /usr/bin/env: «node»: Нет такого файла или каталога. Хочу запустить проект через npm. Но не работает

Tags: webstorm

Запускаю проект через npm. Не хочет. Вручную запускаю через ng serve. Работает. В чем проблема.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node` нет в `$PATH`. Будет ли та же команда работать в системном терминале? Если да, попробуйте запустить WebStorm из того же терминала (с помощью `bin/webstorm.sh`) - это должно помочь.

На linux переменные окружения, установленные в `.bashrc` (`.zshrc`, etc.) доступны только тем приложениям, которые запускаются из терминала. Приложениям, запущенным иным образом (с рабочего стола, через меню System, etc.), доступны только переменные из конфигурации login shell (`~/.profile`, etc).
Возможные воркэраунды описаны в [IDEABKL-7589](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589)